# NameError: name 'env' is not defined

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to  train a model to solve the FrozenLake-v0 problem.

In the process am trying to instantiate the environment in the following way. But encountering an error. Please help me with this

```
!apt install xvfb -y
!pip install pyvirtualdisplay
!pip install piglet

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
pip install gym
import torch
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pip install pyglet
env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v0')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-3d8d6ba4b349> in <module>()
----> 1 env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v0')

NameError: name 'gym' is not defined
```

Comment: Your question body indicates a different error from your question title - which is it? [ask]

Comment: Indeed, you are not defining the name `gym` anywhere in the code, either as a variable or as an imported module.  What did you expect `gym` to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not add `import gym` in the beginning...